# How can I get a dependent dropdown selected value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am new at development, right now I am learning laravel 9 and I am trying to get a dependent dropdown selected value. Here is my blade file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="vendor_state">State</label>
    <select class="form-control" style="color: #000;" id="vendor_state" name="vendor_state">
        <option selected disabled>Select State</option> @foreach ($states as $state)
        <option value="{{ $state->id }}" @if(!empty($state->id==$vendorDetails['state'])) selected @endif>{{ $state->name }}</option> @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="vendor_city">City</label>
    <select class="form-control" style="color: #000;" id="vendor_city" name="vendor_city"></select>
</div>
```

And here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#vendor_state').on('change', function () {
        var stateId = this.value;
        $('#vendor_city').html('');
        $.ajax({
            headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            url: '{{ route('cities') }}?state_id='+stateId,
            type: 'get',
            success: function (res) {
                var dropdown = $('#vendor_city');
                dropdown.html('<option selected disabled value="">Select City</option>');
                $.each(res, function (key, value) {
                    dropdown.append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

For now, I can save the values of the state and the city in the database and get the selected value of the state. How can I get the selected value of the city?

I tried storing the selected value in dropdown var and display it using if condition inside the option value of the script.

Comment: You can save all the cities in a javascript variable and whenever the state changes, you find it's related cities from the cities variable instead of using ajax.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking or trying to do. "*How can I get the selected value of the city?*" - after the form is submitted, selected city will be available in your controller method as `$request-> vendor_city`.  If you mean in JS, it will be `$('#vendor_city').val()`. "*I tried storing the selected value in dropdown var*" - how? Where?  "*display it using if condition inside the option value of the script*" - not clear what this means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago, I wrote a similar script for another system. Chose country, then a dropdown with Regions(states) list appears. Upon Choosing a region, a list of Departments (Cities) appears.

Note:
In the database, I have relations from Regions (states) to Countries and from Departments to regions. I.e.:

In the Regions database table, I have a field named "country_id", and in the Departments table I have a column "region_id"

My code was as follows:

The main page with the dropdowns

```
//Country drop-down select
<select style="max-width:150px;" name="country_id" id="country-list" onChange="getRegion(this.value);">
    //Options with list of countries names and ID in foreach loop
    <option value="' . $country->id . '">' . $country->name . '</option>
</select>

<select name="region_id" id="region-list" onChange="getDepartment(this.value);">
    <option value=""><?= $langs->trans('SelectRegion') ?></option>
</select>

<select name="department_id" id="department-list" class="demoInputBox">
    <option value=""><?= $langs->trans('SelectDepartment') ?></option>
</select>
```

The AJAx function:

```
function getRegion(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "region.inc.php",
        data: 'country_id=' + val,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#region-list").html(data);
        }
    });
}
function selectCountry(val) {
    $("#search-box").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
function getDepartment(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "department.inc.php",
        data: 'region_id=' + val,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#department-list").html(data);
        }
    });
}
function selectRegion(val) {
    $("#search-box").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

"region.inc.php" is:

```
$country_id = $_POST['country_id'];

<option value=""><?= $langs->trans('SelectRegion') ?></option>

$regions_array = function_to_get_regions_ids_and_names_in_array

foreach ($regions_array as $result) {
    print '<option value="' . $result->region_id . '">' . $result->department_id . '</option>';
}
```

"departments.inc.php"

```
$region_id = $_POST['region_id'];

$departments_array = function_to_get_departments_ids_and_names_in_array

<option value=""><?= $langs->trans('SelectDepartment') ?></option>

foreach ($departments_array as $result) {
    print '<option value="' . $result->department_id . '">' . $result->department_name . '</option>';
}
```